# Need a Magento 2 report

Tags: orders, customer-account, reports

I'm looking for a specific report. We need a monthly report of orders that includes the customer's name/address and what they purchased. (Magento 2.3.6)  I don't see this in the standard reports. My google searches have only come up with rather expensive packages of reports. Can anyone point me either a way to code this report or an add-on that doesn't include 40 reports I don't need?

Thanks Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advance Reporting:-

I am using this reporting extension, you can check i am getting customer report like this.

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-advanced-reports.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't expecting free, but it's much appreciated.